How do I call the contract function using ethers.js with bytes parameter, encryptedSecretsUrl? Using Chainlink Functions, sendRequest function
This worked with remix
This worked without use of encryptedSecretsUrl using ethers.js. It worked in remix, but it didn't work with ethers.js.
  provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
  const signer = await provider.getSigner();
  console.log(signer.address);
    
  MyContract = new ethers.Contract(NFTcontract, myabi, signer);
  console.log(MyContract);
  const result = await MyContract.sendRequest("<MY_GIST_SECRET_URL>", stringArray);

The function is this one on the contract:
    function sendRequest(
        bytes memory encryptedSecretsUrls,
        string[] memory args    
        )
        external
        returns (bytes32 requestId)
    {
        FunctionsRequest.Request memory req;
        req.initializeRequestForInlineJavaScript(source); // Initialize the request with JS code
        if (encryptedSecretsUrls.length > 0)
            req.addSecretsReference(encryptedSecretsUrls);
        // Send the request and store the request ID
        if (args.length > 0) req.setArgs(args);
        s_lastRequestId = _sendRequest(
            req.encodeCBOR(),
            subscriptionID,
            gasLimit,
            donID
        );

        return s_lastRequestId;
    }

The following was the error:
estimateGas, return=null


add please more information with example data

My apologies, it's my first time here so I'm not used to creating posts.
I just found out that I forgot to add my contract as chainlink subscription consumer which was the mistake.
Sending encryptedSecretsUrl as a string to call the function worked perfectly fine. Thank you.

No problem. Just usually, people don't bother to read the question if they see there isn't enough information or a simple example :)

I just found out that I forgot to add my contract as chainlink subscription consumer which was the mistake. Sending encryptedSecretsUrl as a string to call the function worked perfectly fine. Thank you.
  const result = await MyContract.sendRequest("<MY_GIST_SECRET_URL>", stringArray);


